# Stopping the Jetty Server in the Maven-GWT-Plugin

Tags: gwt, maven, intellij-idea

This is more of an annoyance than anything else. However, I'm using the Maven integration with IntelliJ IDEA to run the Maven-GWT-Plugin's "gwt:debug" goal. However, there doesn't seem to be any goal like "gwt:stop", so I have to start the task manager and manually kill the java.exe goal.

Like I said, it's more of an annoyance than anything else, but when I make a change and have to rebuild, it's a real pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `gwt:debug` is "blocking", closing the DevMode window should be enoughto stop the DevMode process thus the maven build.

Doesn't IntelliJ have some kind of "task manager" itself for things it launched?

Comment: There's a "stop" button, but it doesn't kill the java.exe process. Don't know if this is an IntelliJ bug or not.

Comment: FYI, I updated my answer. I forgot that there's the DevMode window, that you can just close to end the "debug".